# Randomly occuring Segmentation faults when writing data

Tags: c++

I have the following scenario, I divide a file of size *n* into a set of smaller chunks **C** where each *c* in **C** is of the same size *k* and I need to store all *c* on disk. Each *c* is represented as a `std::vector<uint8_t>` and in write to file with and identifier which is a SHA-1 representation of *c* as a `std::string`. I write *c* to disk using this function:

```
    bool vector_disk_writer(const std::string path, const std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
    {

        const uint8_t* cdata = data.data();

        FILE* fp; // File pointer 
        if((fp=fopen(path.c_str(), "wb"))==NULL) {
            printf("Cannot open file.\n");
            return false;

        }
        bool result = true;
        if (fwrite(cdata, sizeof(uint8_t), data.size(), fp) != data.size())
        {
            result = false;
        }
        fclose(fp);

        return result;
}
```

I do this for multiple files, but identify if *c* is all ready stored on disk, if its I don't call the function above. So essentially data duplication avoidance.

Now my problem is that if I have *k* = 4kB then after writing roughly 8.5million files I start seeing segmentation faults and with *k* = 1kB I see it at around 16.5 milion files. 
The segmentation fault happens when I call `vector_disk_writer` function and I am not sure why. I originally thought it was due to to many open file discriptors, but the application is not run in parallel and I have not had the function return `false` on me yet.

I have used valgrind with following parameters `--tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes` which return no erros.

So any ideas why this may cause segmentation faults?

EDIT: 
Update the code example and secondly, I ran it on a different server and it actually prints the error:`Cannot open file` after I update the function to the above. So the chance is I guess that it is something to do with file descriptors or inodes?

Comment: This is not C. It's C++. Why are you using `fwrite` and such when coding C++?

Comment: You should not `fwrite` your file if `fopen` failed. Some `return false;` in the `if` block is needed.

Comment: And replacing `printf("Cannot open file.\n")` by `perror(path.c_str());` will gives you more interesting information

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sizeof(uint8_t) * data.size()` as a second parameter of `fwrite` function call?

Comment: You should also `fclose` even if the writing failed. This is much harder to get wrong if you use `std::ofstream`.

Comment: @vahancho No, the call to `fwrite` is correct: [size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
FILE *stream)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite)

Comment: @vahancho The third parameter is the number of elements, the second is each element's size.

Comment: @Mathieu true thanks. But not part of this error. I have not seen cannot open message :)

Comment: @Broman performance, it is faster than what I found provided in C++

Comment: @molbdnilo true but `ofstream` is slower, at least from the test I did.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and I will update with your comments.

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, what filesystem are you dumping 16.5 million files on, and dare I ask, how long does it take to sequentially write that many files of even 1KB in size? I ask because some fs, ntfs for example, pukes rather violently with that many nodes in the same folder. Regardless, is there something wrong with running this in a debugger and seeing exactly where the fault originates? It seems you've done everything *but* that.

Comment: @WhozCraig EXT4 and it takes a "while" I don't know with writing on its own, but with duplication avoidance a couple of hours

Comment: I assume you already checked your available inodes on that volume?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes I have used 8%

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I just need to drag these out. That 8% is *after* your program faults and craps 16+ million nodes on disk? percentage really doesn't matter. its the number of total and available I was curious about. `df -i`

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry 10% and yes it is after: `/dev/sdc1       244195328 23883820  220311508   10% /home/scaledemo/ext4`

Comment: ok. thanks. sure doesn't look like it's running out of inodes. If these were going  into subfolders rooted from single location and you were breaching 64k subs I'd be concerned but it sounds like they're all going in that one root. That's just odd. Have you rigged a test program that just dumps 20byte files into a folder and presses the fs to see if the same behavior transpires outside of your program? And of course, there's letting it run overnight in a real debugger.

Comment: @WhozCraig no, trying now

Comment: @WhozCraig should this `(fp=fopen(path.c_str(), "wb"))==NULL` catch if fp is null ?

Comment: @LarsNielsen Yes, it should.

Comment: I have found the problem... and it is is craptastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time trying to identify issues with my code besides what is mentioned in the comments above, I came to the conclusion that is what not, in fact, my code that was the problem.

After modifying the write function above to the following:

```
    bool vector_disk_writer(const std::string path, const std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
    {

        const uint8_t* cdata = data.data();

        FILE* fp; // File pointer 
        if((fp=fopen(path.c_str(), "wb"))==NULL) {
            perror(path.c_str());
            return false;
        }

        bool result = true;
        if (fwrite(cdata, sizeof(uint8_t), data.size(), fp) != data.size())
        {
            result = false;
        }
        fclose(fp);

        return result;
}
```

I still got the segmentation fault but much rare, but from what I could tell `perror` was always called. The error was no more space left on device, even though according to `df` I had only used about 25% in total. Now a friend of mine remembered a feature in EXT file systems called `dir_index`, which enables quicker indexing of directories using hash tables. Which is all cool, except for the fact that the table per dir has an upper limit, which I have been unable to find. If you disable `dir_index` the code will work, but you will take a MAJOR performance hit.